# GWT emulation for com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a way to use this `com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson` package along with any Object that extends from it in GWT?

If none, what is the approch to be use the models from `com.google.api.client.json.*` with GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google-http-java-client is not a GWT library, so it's not an option for GWT.

To deal with JSON you have different alternatives:

- the most tiresome to me is the classic com.google.gwt.json.client.
- A better approach is to use elemental.json included with gwt-elemental, which can be run in gwt and jvm
- If you prefer handle json as normal POJOs in your code you have [autobeans](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html) in GWT (Also can be used in JVM)
- I would rather use [gwtquery Databinding](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding) since it's much easier, light way, the syntax to consume webservices is quite simple, and it's also usable in the JVM.

[Edited]

Other options

- [Overlay types](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) you have to write as many methods as attributes you want to access. It is tedious because you have to deal with jsni and it's issues. gwtquery databinding uses basically this approach, but facilitating the work with its generator. Obviously Overlay types do not work in the JVM, so you cannot test that logic in your presenters.
- The future of GWT is to use [JsInterop](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tir74SB-ZWrs-gQ8w-lOEV3oMY6u6lF2MmNivDEihZ4/edit) so as you can access jso properties just defining interfaces. JsInterop is a feature very experimental in 2.7.0 which would be stable in gwt-3.0.0

Comment: How is Elemental useful for representing JSON as POJO and vise versa

Comment: You are missing the most useful option, IMHO, [Javascript overlay types](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html). Bascially, you define thin wrappers around JSON data, which then can be used as a POJO.

Comment: @IgorKlimer updated my coment, IMO Overlay types and JSNI is an option for js lovers who like writing js, for java developers could be a pain.

Comment: Elemental JSON does not useful to represent POJO, it's just for transversing JSON.

Comment: I was thinking more of emulating the GenericJson into GWT

Comment: So unless you port or you rewrite the entire library to work in gwt there is no option since http-java-client uses classes which only work in JVM. That is one of the reasons google wrote elemental-json: to have an implementation which works in both sides.